# Button.setClickable(false) is not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view

I have set `mButton.setClickable(false);` in my code but still this button is invoked by global `button.setOnClickListener` of my code.

EDIT: sorry for the delayed update. Below is the details view where I face the issue.
inside my listview customAdapter class getView method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    YourWrapper wrapper = null;
    HashMap<String, Object> cTa= new HashMap<String, Object>();
    cTa= d.getPosition(position)
    Button mButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mBtn);
    if (row == null)
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        wrapper = new YourWrapper (row);
        row.setTag(wrapper);
    }
    else
        wrapper = (YourWrapper) row.getTag();

     if(success)
        {
                    // section-1
            mButton.setClickable(true);
        }
        else{
                   // section-2
            mButton.setClickable(false);
            mButton.setFocusable(false);
        }
    wrapper.getButton().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //operation
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

Above is the current code which working,and on section-2 it makes the mButton clickable- false, and focusable - false but still it's listen the below  wrapper.getButton().setOnClickListener() and perform the operation. Please suggest me. Sorry for delayed update. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I have made below hot-fixes that solve the problem for now.

```
// section-2
mButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mButton.setClickable(false);
mButton.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: Is this your whole code? Is `mButton` the same as `wrapper.getButton()`? If so, why don't you put the part with `setOnClickListener` in your section-1?

Answer (score 58):

That seems to be by design. This is from the documentation of the [View.setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29)  method:

> Register a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked. If this view is not clickable, it becomes clickable.

Comment: srsly..."If this view is not clickable, it becomes clickable." is a huge design flaw in my opinion. Thanks for the answer, this should be accepted.

Comment: I agree with @JacksOnF1re. Android is a seriously rushed job with some of the dumbest design decisions. The same with button `setAlpha(0);` - the button is still clickable even when alpha is 0. Who in their sane mind would make a button invisible and still let it be clickable, under what circumstance would one want that in their app? Some silly guessing game with invisible buttons? Guess where I am! *rolls eyes*

Answer (score 52):

Instead of using `setClickable(false)` use `setEnabled(false)`

Comment: @ADT I have edited the answer. Do try and let me know the outcome :)

Comment: @jozze using both setClickable and setEnabled worked for me

Comment: using `setEnable(false)` if there is background for view , it disappears

Answer (score 11):

Put setClickable after setOnClickListener

```
mBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
mBtn.setClickable(false);
```

if you put setClickable(false) before setOnClickListener(this), it doesn't work.

Comment: This looks pretty good answer, but I wonder why it is not still upvoted

Comment: @Jeyaseelan because the same answer was already given 6 years before this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18825890/1080954

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using setClickable(false) use following

```
button.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

I had the same problem in my app where i needed to set my button not to clickable in certain conditions. this worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use `View.setOnClickListener()` before `View.setClickable()` ,or the method `setOnclickLisnter()` will set the flag true.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for the answer, but for some weird reason

```
mBtn.setClickable(true);
```

stops the view from getting clicked and

```
mBtn.setClickable(false);
```

makes it clickable again.

Answer (score 1):

on xml

android:enabled="false"

android:alpha="0.5"

dynamically

yourButtonId.alpha = 0.5f

yourButtonId.isEnabled = false

Comment: Yes, it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can check like if(!view.isClickable()) return;

Answer (score 0):

This will work in case of Imageview as well as the button.

```
 private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (imageview.isEnabled()){
            //I have wrapped all code inside onClick() in this if condition
            //Your onClick() code will only execute if the imageview is enabled
            //Now we can use setEnabled() instead of setClickable() everywhere
        }}
    };
```

Inside `onCreate()`, you can do `setEnabled(false)` which will be equivalent to `setClickable(false)`.

We are able to use `setEnabled()` as tag because it's state remains uneffected on invocation of click (unlike `setClickable()` whose state changes).

Answer (score 0):

Like Other friends said, setOnClickListener will override the flag to true.
 So the Workaround is to setOnTouchEvent `return true` whenever you want to disable clicks and set it to `retrun false` when you want to enable click events. 
This is because onTouchEvent is called before every clickListener you define for a view, so returning true will say to all listeners that :

> "Ok, I received this event here, nobody else can receive it".

So your solution may be something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    YourWrapper wrapper = null;
    HashMap<String, Object> cTa= new HashMap<String, Object>();
    cTa= d.getPosition(position)
    Button mButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mBtn);
    if (row == null)
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        wrapper = new YourWrapper (row);
        row.setTag(wrapper);
    }
    else
        wrapper = (YourWrapper) row.getTag();

     if(success)
        {
                    // section-1
            mButton.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> false);
        }
        else{
                   // section-2
            mButton.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> true);
        }
    wrapper.getButton().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //operation
        }
    });
    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Set the click listener to null

`someView.setOnClickListener(null)`

As *[@Jan notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18825890/2253682)*, the `setOnClickListener` enables the click listener automatically. Therefore, a null click listener can be set to disable future clicks. After setting the view to a null click listener, there are no adverse effects to future clicks on that view.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do it on Spinner, and only this one worked for me:

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
                return@setOnTouchListener true
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked setClickable(true) and setClickable(false) on Android 4.1.1 and it seems to be working now.