# How setting Clickable attribute in XML works?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I have a `Button` in an `Activity`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
    android:text="Test"      
    android:onClick="onClickEvent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

and a method:

```
public void onClickEvent(View view) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Hey!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

In spite of setting clickable attribute to false in xml, why click event still should work?
does something overrides it?

Comment: android:clickable="false" remove this one

Comment: @Abhinav Gupta, please read the question carefully.

Comment: Patzu, your question is very unclear. If there's problem with XML, you need to clarify who/what generates the XML. In question body you put XML snippet and Javascript snippet. Why & where do you set "OnClick" - in the XML? or where? Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @filiprem if it is unclear how below people could understand and answered it?

Comment: You were lucky :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In spite of setting clickable to false, why click event should work?

`setClickListener` resets that flag.

```
public void More ...setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
2318        if (!isClickable()) {
2319            setClickable(true);
2320        }
2321        mOnClickListener = l;
2322    }
```

and yes `android:onClick="onClickEvent"` calls internally `setOnClickListener`

Comment: Could you please explain more? I did not get you. Why 'onClickEvent' still works? How to prevent it from working?

Comment: don't set the click listner (or set it to null programmatically) or keep a state in your activity/fragment

Comment: The only code I have in my project is above mentioned code. I am not doing anything else.

Comment: and again, `android:onClick="onClickEvent"`, calls `View.setOnClickListener` which calls `setClickable(true);`.

Comment: Thanks, so 'Clickable' attribute in XML is unused?

Comment: it might be used, but it is overridden by `View.setOnClickListener`

Comment: source code is super helpful and it is pretty much self explanatory +1

Answer (score 1):

According to [the most upvoted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825747/button-setclickablefalse-is-not-working/18825890), clickable goes back to true because of the global setOnClickListener method.

Cannot test at the moment, but maybe you could create two separate listeners and switch the one currently used by the button when you need it. So you can switch to a listener that does nothing when you want to disable clicking on it.

Looks a bit overkill to me, and the cleanest method is to use `setEnabled(false)` in my opinion, but try playing around with listeners if you really don't want to use setEnabled.